# CakePHP4 で コードカバレッジが生成できない

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

CakePHP4 でコントローラーのテストを作成し、
コードカバレッジの生成をしようとしましたが生成できません。

下記の記事を参照し、

[Cookbook > テスト > コードカバレッジの生成]
https://book.cakephp.org/4/ja/development/testing.html#id9

こちらの記事に記載のとおり、下記のコマンドを実行しましたが、

```
phpunit --coverage-html webroot/coverage tests/TestCase/Controller/〇〇ControllerTest.php
```

下記のエラーとなり、コードカバレッジが生成されません。

```
Cannot open file "tests/TestCase/Controller/〇〇ControllerTest.php".
```

テスト対象のコントローラーをlsすると下記のように表示されます。
[image: ls]

原因や対処方法など、ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけたら非常にありがたいです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

<各バージョン>
PHP 8.0.12
CakePHP 4.2.10
PHPUnit 3.7.21

※ teratail でも [同じ質問](https://teratail.com/questions/6dfep47hdjemxa) をさせていただいております。

Comment: 開いているコマンドラインのカレントディレクトリから`ls`や`dir /b`を利用して該当のファイルを開けますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
コマンドラインから ls した結果を、本文に記載しました。ご確認よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: また、コマンドラインから start [対象ファイル] で開くことができている状況です。

Answer (score 1):

xdebug の代わりに phpdbg を使用する下記のコマンドで、コードカバレッジが生成できました。

```
phpdbg -qrr vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --coverage-html webroot/coverage tests/TestCase/Controller/○○Test.php
```